# Motodev / Eclipse freezes up for several seconds when autofill tooltip proprosal pops up

Tags: android, eclipse, tooltip

I recently installed a fresh copy of Motodev. When I type the name of object and a period after it a popup comes up with a list of all of the methods available to that object. Ever since I started using this new copy of Motodev if I have an object with a very large amount of available methods this process freezes the whole program for several seconds. 
RelativeLayout and EditText are the two that I have personally noticed that this is a problem with, but I suspect any object that has a large number of methods will cause this. It was never a problem before. Has anyone else seen this issue and if so how did you fix it? I do like having the list pop up so that I can see all of the methods available to me so I'd like to leave that feature turned on if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you figured this out already, but I'll say it for future readers.  There is an update to MOTODEV Studio specifically to work with ADT 8.0.1. There were some API changes in ADT that required us to update Studio also.  ADT 8.0.1 requires Studio 2.0.1, which is based on Eclipse Helios. There are installers on the MOTODEV site as well as an updater for Eclipse.

Because of the complexity of dependencies with all the Eclipse plugins, I suggest to download the .zip archive at MOTODEV rather than using the "Install Updates" method.  I find that I get timeouts quite often at home on broadband that don't happen at work with a bigger pipe.

Also, Studio 2.1 will be available some time within the next week (~Jan 25) and will work with the 2.3 SDK and ADT 8.0.1.

UPDATE: 2/14/11 - It would appear that the correct answer is found at comment #8 in this link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850

Tim will need to formally accept this answer at some point...

Which is as follows:

---

For those of you with this problem, here's what you can do until the fix is publicly available:
1. Download `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/<branch>.tar.gz` where  is one of those listed here (froyo-release for 2.2, the file is about 113MB): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+refs
2. Extract the contents of base/ in the tar into "/platforms/android-/sources" where  is 8 for froyo, 7 for eclair, etc.
3. Enjoy fast content assist in 3.6!

---

Comment: I am using Motodev 2.0.1 and ADT 8.0.1 still getting this freezing issue. I'll upgrade to 2.1 whenever it becomes available.

Comment: Hi Tim. We have the packages queued up. Barring any problems, it should be available tomorrow (Friday). It works with ADT 9 and Gingerbread, as well as the Honeycomb Preview that went out on Wednesday.

Comment: For what its worth, I am still having this problem with the updated version of MotoDev.

Comment: @Tim - We saw a similar bug reported last week on our discussion boards.  One of the posters pointed to a bug on the Android site http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850 which has a workaround (see comment #8). LMK if this is the same behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @Eric Thank you,the suggestion in comment #8 fixed it for me! Now I just have to download all of the other base versions(donut, eclair etc..) so it will work for all of my projects regardless of which version of Android they are built on.

Comment: All went well except for gingerbread. There is a file in there that my Windows XP is saying has too long of a name for me to copy =(. Its the file: ExternalSharedPermsDiffKeyTest.java. Luckily none of my projects are built for gingerbread. Hopefully there is a real fix by the time I am interested in making apps built for this api version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse v3.6 (Helios) this is a known issue with ADT - the android dev site recommends using v3.5 or v3.4 of eclipse until the problem is resolved.

**EDIT:** It might be dependent on the version of ADT you are using - I can't find the recommendation to use v3.4 or v3.5 anymore. Perhaps things were fixed with ADT 8.0.x Check which versions you are using anyway.

Comment: I am using the version of Eclipse that came with stock MotoDev studio version 2.0. I looked in the 'About Motodev' window and it appears that it is in fact eclipse 3.6. I went to 'Install New Software' window and looked at the options for eclipse platform and my only choices shown are 3.6 and 3.6.1 Do you happen to know if 3.6.1 will fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry for double post, it doesn't seem to want me to edit my other comment. It turns out it won't let me install 3.6.1 anyway. So I guess I'll just have to go without this feature for now. Does anyone know if its possible to make this pop-up available as an option on right click or something like that? Or where I can find the option to turn this off?

Comment: @Tim : I don't know about making it a right-click option but I think turning it off might be (in eclipse)...Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation

Comment: @MissterSquonk, yup, your edit is correct.  The latest version of ADT with gingerbread, works fine with eclipse v3.6.  I'm using it right now for my dev environment.